# can not access the public database of kooaba API for wine Labels

Tags: ios6, image-recognition

i am using kooaba API for image recognition.it recognise the image that are uploaded by me in my account but i want to access the public database of kooaba API for wine labels recognition.What i need to do? does they provide in Paid API's Only. please help.here is the link http://www.kooaba.com/en/developers. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kooaba Wine database is not public but can be accessed on request.

You can find more info in the [support center](http://kooaba.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/222639-what-s-in-your-public-database-) or [ask your questions here](http://kooaba.desk.com/customer/portal/emails/new).

Comment: Can you please describe more on this. 
Access to Wine Label Database

I own this plan.
-Recognize 500'000 wine labels
-From € 599.- / month




I can access the image that are uploaded by me in my account but i want to access the public database of kooaba API for wine labels recognition.

What I need to do next?